# Workflow Task is not creating

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom state machine workflow.When I am submitting the request using info-path form,workflow get started ,but no task is created in task list.
I tried to do manual entry in task list ,but still no item is added to task list.
How can I fix this problem? Is there any problem with my task list?